# Checking out master branch from a GitHub Actions workflow fails

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am running the following step on a workflow that runs on pull requests targeting a specific branch.

I am trying to get a specific file that exists on `master` branch.

```
     - name: checkout the mapping from master branch
        shell: bash
        run: |
          ls -al .github
          git branch
          git fetch
          git checkout master -- .github/appvps.yaml
```

Although I see in the logs that the `git fetch` command does fetch `master`

```
* [new branch]            master                  -> origin/master
```

The

```
 git checkout master -- .github/appvps.yaml
```

command fails with

```
fatal: invalid reference: master
```

Why is that?

The command succeeds when executed locally (from a branch other than `master`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the checkout action](https://github.com/actions/checkout):

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    sparse-checkout: |
      .github/appvps.yaml
```

> ```
> # Do a sparse checkout on given patterns. Each pattern should be separated with
> # new lines.
> # Default: null
> sparse-checkout: ''
> ```